# For loop in an opposite direction

Tags: python

I want to make a for loop in python to go over a list. However, I would like to have it going through the list in the opposite direction. For example

```
  foo = [1a,2b,3c,4d]
  for number in foo:
      print number
```

the result of this code should be:
4d
3c
2b
1a
and not 1a 2b 3c 4d.

Any elegant way to do this? Or is it best to reorder the initial list itself?

Many thanks for your advice

Answer (score 7):

```
for number in reversed(foo):
    print number
```

This has the advantage of not creating a reversed copy of `foo`; `reversed` returns a reverse iterator over the list. Also, it works with anything that supports `len` and indexing with integers.

Answer (score 4):

```
foo = [1a,2b,3c,4d]
for number in foo[::-1]:
    print number
```

Answer (score 2):

Just reverse it with slicing notation

```
print foo[::-1]
```

**Output**

```
['4d', '3c', '2b', '1a']
```

Or use [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) function,

```
print "\n".join(reversed(foo))
```

**Output**

```
4d
3c
2b
1a
```